# How to split a line but keep a variable in the line unsplit in python

Tags: python

I have a line that i want to split into three parts:

```
line4 = 'http://www.example.org/lexicon#'+synset_offset+' http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#gloss '+gloss+''
```

The variable gloss contains full sentences, which I dont want to be split. How do I stop this from happening?

The final 3 split parts should be:

```
'http://www.example.org/lexicon#'+synset_offset+'

http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#gloss

'+gloss+''
```

after running `triple = line4.split()`

Comment: If you know there are exactly three parts, you can use `split()`'s `maxsplit` argument.

Comment: would that split it at the first 3 whitespaces it encounters? say if the +gloss+ was "an overwhelming number or amount" would that be left unsplit?

Comment: Try splitting on `#` instead of whitespace.

Comment: The definition of `line4` isn't valid Python... what were you trying to type?

Comment: is that not right? does it still work or is it bad practise? reasonably new to python so i dont know this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm struggling to understand, but why not just create a list to start with:

```
line4 = [
    'http://www.example.org/lexicon#' + synset_offset,
    'http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#gloss',
    gloss
]
```

Simplified example - instead of joining them all together, then splitting them out again, just join them properly in the first place:

```
a = 'hello'
b = 'world'
c = 'i have spaces in me'

d = ' '.join((a,b,c)) # <- correct way
# hello world i have spaces in me
print ' '.join(d.split(' ', 2)) # take joined, split out again making sure not to split `c`, then join back again!?
```

Comment: Sorry, I am putting these three into Turtle format for RDF and the only way the RDFlib will read it is like this

Comment: @Johnnerz okay, then just `' '.join(line4)` afterwards so they're space separated - just seems daft to join them all together, then split them out again...

Answer (score 0):

If they are all begin with "http" you could split them using http as delimiter, otherwise you could do two steps:

First extract the first url from the string by using the space or http as 
    firstSplit=line4.split(' ', 1)

```
firstString= firstSplit.pop(0) -> pop the first url
secondSplit =firstSplit.join() -> join the rest
secondSplit[-1].split('lemon#gloss') ->splits the remaining two
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> synset_offset = "foobar"
>>> gloss = "This is a full sentence."
>>> line4 = 'http://www.example.org/lexicon#'+synset_offset+' http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#gloss '+gloss
>>> import string
>>> string.split(line4, maxsplit=2)
['http://www.example.org/lexicon#foobar', 'http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#gloss', 'This is a full sentence.']
```

Not sure what you're trying to do here. If in general you're looking to avoid splitting a keyword, you should do:

```
>>> string.split(line:line.index(keyword)) + [line[line.index(keyword):line.index(keyword)+len(keyword)]] + string.split(line[line.index(keyword)+len(keyword):])
```

If the gloss (or whatever keyword part) of the string is the end part, that slice will just be an empty string `''`; if that is the case, don't append it, or remove it if you do.